Pólya urn Martingale - interpretation of the martingale property
We consider Pólya's urn, where $B=(B_n)_{n\geq0}$ tracks the number of black marbles added to the urn after $n$ draws. In each turn, we add one extra marble of the same colour as the drawn one, and begin with one black and one white marble. Also $B_0=0$.
I found the following exercise: Let $\theta$ be a fixed number, with $0<\theta<1$. Define $M:=(M_n)_{n\geq0}$ via
$$M_n:=\frac{(n+1)!}{B_n!(n-B_n)!}\theta^{B_n}(1-\theta)^{n-B_n}.$$
This does define a martingale with respect to the canonical filtration generated by $B$. The martingale $M$ is bounded by 0 from below and by 1 from above, because we basically plug in $B_n$ into the density of a Beta-distribution for parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$.
Is this martingale useful for anything? I mean, since it is a martingale, we have constant expectation, i.e.
$$\mathbb E[M_n]=\mathbb E[M_0]=1.$$
That is not interesting, unless one wanted to show integrability of the density of the Beta-distribution (with discrete uniformly chosen parameters, since $B_n\sim U_{[0,n+1]}$) probabilistically and without getting one's hands dirty on integration.
Any other uses?
